# Symfony2: Create both normal and non-login users using FosUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

What would be correct approach in order to create normal users and non-login users using FosUserBundle?

By **non-login** users I mean no username or email provided.

One way would be to generate some fake **usernames/emails** for the **fake users**, but doesn't seem ok.

The other way would be to force the **username/email** fields to be **optional**, but I'm not sure it will work and it won't break the login proccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With FOSUserBundle users with `enabled` set to `false` or `locked` set to `true` are not able to login.

Please read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522238/symfony2-fosuserbundle-how-to-validate-against-user-active-flag-on-login/18533854#18533854) for the explanation of their different purposes.