# symfony2 how to implement AdvancedUserInterface on User class that extends BaseUser?

Tags: class, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a custom User class that extends the BaseUser.

I have been informed that in order to make use of the user lock functions my user class needs to implement the AdvancedUserInterface, but it seems I can't do both EXTENDS and IMPLEMENTS on the User class?

```
<?php
// src/BizTV/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace BizTV\UserBundle\Entity;

use BizTV\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints as BizTVAssert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company as company;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
```

With this approach I get no error messages, but nor do I get the use of the functions for checking a user lock so it appears that nothing happens.

If I switch them up like this,

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface extends BaseUser
```

I get the following error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_EXTENDS, expecting '{' in /var/www/cloudsign/src/BizTV/UserBundle/Entity/User.php on line 18
```

Comment: The FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User implements UserInterface. This interface extends the AdvancedUserInterface. What will you do there is so unnecessary. Use only: "class User extends BaseUser"

Comment: But if I do, the userChecker doesn't check for user==locked or user==disabled, so how will I go about using the user lock methods then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it by doing this:

Add to the User entity my own function to get the Lock status (a variable that I didn't define, it was already in the user class which I am extending from

```
//Below should be part of base user class but doesn't work so I implement it manually.

/**
 * Get lock status
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getLocked()
{
    return $this->locked;
}
```

And in the UserChecker I put this:

```
public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
{

    //Test for companylock...
    if ( !$user->getCompany()->getActive() ) {
        throw new LockedException('The company of this user is locked.', $user);
    }    

    if ( $user->getLocked() ) {
        throw new LockedException('The admin of this company has locked this user.', $user);
    }
```

...

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
{

    //Test for companylock...
    if ( !$user->getCompany()->getActive() ) {
        throw new LockedException('The company of this user is locked.', $user);
    }    

    if ( $user->getLocked() ) {
        throw new LockedException('The admin of this company has locked this user.', $user);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You don't have to create anything.
Just call user->isLocked() :) It was already implemented in the BaseUser class of FOSUserBundle ;)