# Overiding FOS USER Bundle check login request

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I use FOS user bundle for the login part of my web site.
The request checking login+password is generate by FOS.
I need to override it to add some specific control.
How can I do that?

Here is the generated sql :

```
SELECT * FROM admin.adm_utilisateur t0 
WHERE t0.email_canonical = 'jp@yahoo.com' 
LIMIT 1
```

I need to have :

```
SELECT * FROM admin.adm_utilisateur t0 
WHERE t0.email_canonical = 'jp@yahoo.com' 
and t0.utl_sup_date is null 
LIMIT 1
```

Thanks

Comment: what exaclty does this column 'utl_sup_date' mean?

Comment: It's the date when a user has been deleted (we do not delete physicaly).

Comment: So maybe you could just use the build in flags of fos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522238/symfony2-fosuserbundle-how-to-validate-against-user-active-flag-on-login

Comment: what version of FOSUser are you using?  2.0 has events which make this easy.  I can describe more if you post the version.

Answer (score 0):

You should [implement your own `UserManager`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/user_manager.md#overriding-the-user-manager) that would have a customized `findUserByUsername` methodm where you'd formulate a criteria to the query that's used to find a user. Here's [the method you should override](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php#L90).